# Jenkins on Ubuntu: Desktop or Server Installation?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I'm standing up a build server on a fresh machine that will get Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed.  Does it matter whether I use the server or desktop version if Jenkins is the only service targeted to run on the machine?

I currently plan to host this installation as a stand alone Jenkins instance, but may convert it to the slave of my Windows build server later.

Comment: I'd love to know why this got down voted.  Maybe I'm in the wrong place, but at least tell me.  I'd think I'm not the only one installing Linux for a new build server.

Comment: Even I had the same question and got the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Jenkins is the only thing it will be used for and you are comfortable with the CLI you will be best off using the server OS. It is a lot leaner and doesn't contain a gui.

You can always add any of the desktop packages to the server release and if you find you need a GUI in the future you can install gnome with:

`sudo apt-get install gnome-core`

Comment: Helpful advice on how to add a GUI to server, +1 for that.  Any direct experience having jenkins run standalone or as a slave on Ubuntu?

Comment: It really comes down to weather you think you need the GUI or not, the installation and management of Jenkins is the same for both the server release and Desktop.

Comment: I haven't used a windows master before but it looks like it will work fine with a linux slave using the SSH slaves plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Slaves+plugin